# Updating fields on existing Open Graph objects

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I've got a web app that needs to update the values of fields in existing Open Graph objects. In particular I'm trying to edit the location on photos.

However I find I'm unable to directly alter any field at all. I've been experimenting with the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) using the POST method and an access_token with 'user_photos', 'publish_stream' and 'user_photo_video_tags' permissions. I've trying setting a photo's field 'caption' to another string value, and also the 'place' field to another Place ID such as 127571667351223 for Melbourne International Airport. When I click Submit for these commands, the response window just says 'true'. However when I check the Object, no change has occurred to it.

Can anyone explain why these changes aren't going through?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the console/test tool doesn't actually make the change, but simulates it and returns the response as if it did it. Try using some live code.

Comment: I've tried doing this in live code now (as well as Graph API Explorer with my Application selected) and still I get a 'true' response, but no change is made.

I've also noticed you can type in any random string for the field name and it still returns 'true', so I can't even be sure the field name correct. :/